# For loop with json.loads issue

Tags: python

I have a file (Log.txt) containing 2 JSON - one in each row:

```
{"ts":"2017-11-19T11:11:01.394","v":{"path":"D:\\Tableau Extract\\Logs\\log.txt"}}
{"ts":"2017-11-19T11:11:01.394",["v":{"path":"D:\\Tableau Extract\\Logs\\log_bk.txt"]}}
```

I try to iterate each row and read it as a JSON format, however, when my loop gets to the second row it fails because of the square barrackts before the JSON.

when I try to run the following code:

```
import json
for row in df['ColumnName']:
    x = json.loads(row)
    print x
```

I get the following error:

> {"ts":"2017-11-19T11:11:01.394","v":{"path":"D:\Tableau
>   Extract\Logs\log.txt"}}Extract\Logs\log.txt"}} TypeError: expected
>   string or buffer

Note that Python does print the first row, but fails on the other. 
Any suggestions how to deal with such inconsistency?

I am using Python 2.7 with Jupyter Notebook.

Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: That 2nd row isn't valid JSON. You _can_ easily use `str` methods to get rid of those brackets, but it would be better to find out why the data is like that in the first place. If it's supposed to be valid JSON then the program that's producing it is broken. If the data _is_ supposed to look like that then you need to find out the actual data format that's being used and process it accordingly.

Comment: This is a Tableau log file, kind of a "black box" for me (since Tableau don't support log parsing). I need a solution which could be flexible enough to iterate through thousands of rows while still capturing the inner JSON in the square brackets, in case there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that "repairs" the string in the 2nd row by simply removing the brackets. It works in Python 2 and Python 3 with the given data, but it may fail on more complicated data.

```
import json

data = r'''
{"ts":"2017-11-19T11:11:01.394","v":{"path":"D:\\Tableau Extract\\Logs\\log.txt"}}
{"ts":"2017-11-19T11:11:01.394",["v":{"path":"D:\\Tableau Extract\\Logs\\log_bk.txt"]}}
'''.splitlines()

for row in data:
    if not row:
        continue
    row = row.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    d = json.loads(row)
    print(d)
```

**Python 2 output**

```
{u'ts': u'2017-11-19T11:11:01.394', u'v': {u'path': u'D:\\Tableau Extract\\Logs\\log.txt'}}
{u'ts': u'2017-11-19T11:11:01.394', u'v': {u'path': u'D:\\Tableau Extract\\Logs\\log_bk.txt'}}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you sir!